# Ping Identity switch user

Tags: cookies, pingfederate

Here at my company, we started using Ping Federate as our Identity provider, this is linked with the AD for user info and so on.

The login works via the OAuth page, and this works great, I can login, do things, then when my `access_token`expires this get's refreshed and I can continue without the user even noticing it.

But now I got the request of one of the users if he could switch logins.
but this isn't possible, because when I click login, the popup of PingFederate that get's fired doesn't asks for the credentials, it just continues and uses the last credentials.

However when i clean my cookies and I login it asks for the credentials again, but I can't ask the users to clear all it's cookies whenever he wants to switch users.

I tried clearing the cookies of the PingFederate Domain when I logout, but no luck:

`me.$cookies.remove('PF', {domain: 'federation.xxx.com'});`

any body else has an idea what I can do to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use PingFederate's logout features to achieve what you're after.

- If you're using just the HTML Form Adapter to log in users, then you can configure a logout path in your adapter instance that you can ask users to go to to logout. See "Logout Path" here: https://support.pingidentity.com/s/document-item?bundleId=pingfederate-93&topicId=ttq1564003023121.html
- Alternatively you could enable single logout (SLO) which will trigger a logout at all adapters or other authentication sources the user may have logged in to. For more details, see:

  - https://support.pingidentity.com/s/document-item?bundleId=pingfederate-93&topicId=php1564002958041.html
  - https://support.pingidentity.com/s/document-item?bundleId=pingfederate-93&topicId=pqn1564002990312.html

Comment: Absolutely that could be used as part of the logout process, but isn't required if the need is just to "switch user".